# Sources of topograpical maps for use in LaTeX documents

Tags: data-request, geospatial, tool-request

I would like to add a partial map of Prague into my LaTeX document but I am lost where to begin search for maps and how to get them into the document. I suppose that once I can get EPS or PDF of map area, I can manage from there. However I do not know where to start searching for map data that would be reasonably easy to convert to PDF or EPS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you had a look at openstreetmap?

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmbook

Not tested myself, they use Latex to generate the book.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. It is definitely a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [world street map dataset](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/world-street-map) available that has content for Prague, as well as other areas in the world.  [More street data for Prague](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=street&sort=score%20desc,%20name%20asc&ext_location=&ext_bbox=14.17236328125,49.938847502925306,14.7271728515625,50.17865705409927&ext_prev_extent=14.14764404296875,49.88224746043338,14.75189208984375,50.23490869265562) is also available.

Additional, you can find related datasets for this (or other) geographical area in the world on Data.gov by drawing a boundary around the geographical space you are searching at the new [Data.gov catalog](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset).  To look for a specific file format, browse the formats on the left side of the page.

(Disclaimer: I am the Evangelist for Data.gov.)